# Typescript + NestJs + Class Transformer: How to use generic types in response DTO?

Tags: typescript, pagination, nestjs, class-transformer

I have multiple endpoints that return a response including pagination details. I would like to use one parent type for the pagination and pass in different data-types for the `data` param.

I tried the following, but this was not working because the statement in `@Type` gives the error `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`, so it expects a value/class and not a type:

```
export class PaginatedResponseDto<T> {
  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty()
  skip: number;

  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty()
  take: number;

  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty()
  count: number;

  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty()
  @Type(() => T[]) // <- this is not working, because I cannot use `T` here
  data: T[];

  constructor(data: any) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

I searched and [found this](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/tree/master/sample/sample4-generics), which is basically working, but unfortunately it seems to transform the response twice, which causes issues with dates.

Is there any other way to do this (instead of writing multiple `PaginatedResponseDto`-classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something along this line...

```
export class PaginatedResponseDto<T> {

  @Exclude()
  private type: Function;

  @Expose()
  @ApiProperty()
  @Type(opt => (opt.newObject as PaginatedResponseDto<T>).type)
  data: T[];

  constructor(type: Function) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about that, because my validation doesnt check the `data` object.
Validation of main CloudEvent works properly, but data object is not checked at all.
Did I understand something wrong?
Really sorry for formatting.

`export class CloudEvent<T> {`
`@Exclude()`
`private dataType?: Function;`


`@IsString()`
`id: string;`


`@ValidateNested()`
`@Type(options => (options.newObject as CloudEvent<T>).dataType)`
`data: T;`


`constructor(dataType: Function) {`
`this.dataType = dataType;`
`}`
`}`

`export class CustomerCloudEventDto extends CloudEvent<CustomerDto> {}`

Comment: @AleksandraG did you manage to solve this issue? tried it as well, but it doesnt validate inner object

Comment: @SagiRika I ended up with:

export class CloudEventDto {
  @IsString()
  id: string;

  @IsString()
  version: string;

  @IsEnum(EVENT)
  type: EVENT;

  @ValidateNested()
  @Type((type: TypeHelpOptions | undefined) => {
    if (type?.object) {
      const cloudEvent: CloudEventDto = type.object as CloudEventDto;
      switch (cloudEvent.type) {
        case EVENT.C_CREATED:
          return CCreatedDto;
        case EVENT.C_UPDATED:
          return CUpdatedDto;
      }
    }
    return CCreatedDto;
  })
  data: CCreatedDto || CUpdatedDto;
}